# React unit test for a text field wraped inside context when focus event fires React testing libray and jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have this **StakeSelection.tsx** component

```
<StakeProvider>
      <Grid container spacing={1}>
        <Grid item>
          <StakeInput fieldName="stake" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <StakeInput fieldName="flexibleStake" />
        </Grid>
        <Keyboard />
      </Grid>
    </StakeProvider>
```

What this does is when the user is focused `(onFocus event)` on a component, context is updated in a field called `focusedFieldName`

So if the user focused on the stake field, `focusedFieldName = "stake"`
when the user focused on flexiblestake field, `focusedFieldName = "flexibleStake"`

I need to write a unit test for this using jest and react testing library.

**This is my test code**

```js
import React from "react";
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";

import StakeInput from "./stake-input";
import { StakeProvider } from "../../context/Stake";

jest.mock("../../context/Stake.js", () => {
  const useStake = jest.fn(() => ({
    stake: 0,
    focusedFieldName: "",
    setFocus: jest.fn(),
    flexibleStake: 0,
    stayFocused: false,
    removeFocus: jest.fn(),
  }));

  return {
    useStake,
  };
});

describe("stakeInput", () => {
  it("should render", () => {
    <StakeProvider>
      <StakeInput />
    </StakeProvider>;
  });

  it('should focusedFieldName "stake" when focused on stake field', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(
      <StakeProvider>
        <StakeInput fieldName="stake" />
      </StakeProvider>
    );

    const stakeInput = getByTestId("stake-input");

    fireEvent.focus(stakeInput);

    expect(stakeInput).toHaveFocus();
    expect(useStake().focusedFieldName).toBe("stake");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

When I run this I am getting this errors

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> ```
>   28 |
>   29 |   it('should focusedFieldName "stake" when focused on stake field', () => {
> > 30 |     const { getByTestId } = render(
>      |                                   ^
>   31 |       <StakeProvider>
>   32 |         <StakeInput fieldName="stake" />
>   33 |       </StakeProvider>
> ```

Also in this line

```
expect(useStake().focusedFieldName).toBe("stake");
```

I am getting this error `Cannot find name 'useStake'.`

How do I fix this errors with React and RTL?

Answer (score 0):

In the "should render" test, you need to add a return statement to render the component. The test is currently not doing anything, and you should use the render function to actually render the component.
Also you are mocking the useStake hook, so you need to import it from the mocked module.

```js
import { StakeProvider, useStake } from "../../context/Stake"
```

Also double check if your provider is a named or default export and you are importing it correctly in your test. 
Unfortunately though these steps will solve some errors, the main issue might remain. I came accross simillar problem and managed to solve it.  Mocking the useContext(useStake in your case) hook was a major headache. I will try to mimic your test as closely as possible.

```js
import React from "react"
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react"

import { StakeProvider, useStake } from "....context file path"
import StakeInput from "....the component path"

jest.mock("./contexts/Stake", () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual("...context file pah") // Import the original module to access the actual context value.

  return {
    ...originalModule,
     __esModule: true, // Set this flag if the module has a default export
    useStake: jest.fn(() => ({
      focusedFieldName: "stake", // Make sure to set the expected value for focusedFieldName here. 
      setFocusedFieldName: jest.fn(),
    })),
  }
})

describe("stakeInput", () => {
  it('should focusedFieldName "stake" when focused on stake field', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(
      <StakeProvider>
        <StakeInput />
      </StakeProvider>
    )

    const stakeInput = getByTestId("stake-input")

    fireEvent.focus(stakeInput)

    expect(stakeInput).toHaveFocus()
    expect(useStake().focusedFieldName).toBe("stake")
  })
})
```

Even after this, I think you will run into a different issue. But nothing that you can't solve by yourself. Here's a [link](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/276) that was helpful, in case you do face the focusing issue. 
Edit:
Just to add, in my case this worked.

```js
    stakeInput.focus() // instead of fireEvent.focus(stakeInput)
```